# Integrating parse in Xcode7 beta

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to integrate parse in my swift project via xcode7 beta,I have added Parse frame work and also added all other dependencies, but when I try to import Parse in  AppDelegate Xcode is  telling "No such module 'parse'",I'm sure that I have linked all the dependency and Parse framework in BuildPhases and as I'm using pure swift there is no need of bridging header. Any help will be appreciated...

[image]

[image: Unable import Parse]

Comment: you havent imported Bolts Framework maybe its causing problem?

Comment: and swift2 is causing hell of problem with everything

Comment: Hi sriram ,you could see the Bolts frame work in the linked binary list at the top itself .

Answer (score 0):

Try below thing,

- Create a new Objective C file in your project (File->New->File
  [Objective C for iOS]).
- Accept the prompt to create a bridging header file between
  Objective C and Swift.
- In the Bridging header file, import your framework using the standard
  Objective C import syntax (e.g. #import ).
- Now you don't need to import the swift in AppDelegate. You can now write code that utilise whatever framework as long as it is imported in bridging header. It is available in entire project.

Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: But the thing is I dont want those frameworks to be in objective-c,parse is directly giving me swift APIs,so I dont want to use objc and bridging header

Comment: Parse framework is still managed using the Objective-C. The API which you are referring is the way to access the objective-c code in swift.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can use parse in xcode7. The problem you're facing i faced too with xcode7 beta2. It's related to xcode not being able to find the framework on your hard disk. 
The solution:

1. Add the framework as usual( drag ,drop , select copy if needed).
2. Then click on the project tab in your xcode. Go to build settings
3. Search for "framework search path". 
   Expand it & double click to the right of the table & press the pulse sign.
4. Write the exact path of where the framework files are. Don't use the recursive option because that will disable autocompletion. Just type the exact path of the directory where the framework files for your project are available.
5. Voila. You now have parse filly enabled